# Why the pop() and del() not indexing problem? PLEASE FIX IT

Tags: python, list, indexing

Sample List : `['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']`

Expected Output : `['Green', 'White', 'Black']`

so i tried using `remove()`, `pop()`, `del()`
but having same problem in indexing. it is taking 'red' as [0] index but skipping 'green' and taking 'white' as [1] index where 'green' should be [1]

i wrote this

```
del List[0]

del List[4]

del List[5]

print(List)
```

i'm getting this error:

```
del List[5]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

but when i write this

```
del List[0]

del List[4]

del List[3]

print(List)
```

i get desired result. Why?

Comment: Please read your question, it's formatting is completely messed up. Also, if you want help with code, you need to extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Here's a hint: how many elements are in the list before you do `del List[0]`? How many elements are in the list after you do `del List[0]`? What is the position of `'Pink'` before you do `del List[0]`? What is the position of `'Pink'` after you do `del List[0]`?

Comment: You should accept an answer if it solved your issue. Otherwise your question remains in the queue for more answers. Also, if you find any answer helpful you should upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you delete an element, the index number for each element change in the new list.

```
List= ['Red', 'Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']

del List[0]
```

Now List is ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']

Now 'Green' is index 0 and 'Yellow' is index 4.

```
del List[4]
```

Now 'Yellow' is removed.

Since now there's no element with index 5, the code below will produce error.

```
del List[5]
```

Comment: If you know which indices in the original list you want to zap, a workaround is to remove them from highest to lowest. Then none of the items you care about will move when the indices change.

Answer (score 0):

You started with this
List= ['Red', 'Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']

On ---> del List[0]
'Red' gets deleted

Your List is List=['Green','White','Black','Pink','Yellow']
index is              0   ,   1   ,  2    ,  3   ,   4

on ---del List[4]

'Yellow' Gets Deleted
now List = ['Green','White','Black','Pink']
index          0    ,   1  ,     2  ,     3

on ---del List[5]
You Are trying To access The Index which doesn't Exist as Now List have Index from 0 to 3

Answer (score 0):

Initially:

```
List= ['Red', 'Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
```

---

> del List[0]

Gives:

```
List= ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
```

---

> del List[4]

Gives:

```
List= ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink']
```

---

> del List[5]

Throws error. As the length of the list is just `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your code line by line :

**Code 1:**

```
lst= ['Red', 'Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
del lst[0] # lst = ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
del lst[4] # lst = ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink']
del lst[5] # error as the max index remaining in the updated list is 3
print(lst)
```

**Code 2**

```
lst= ['Red', 'Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
del lst[0] # lst = ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
del lst[4] # lst = ['Green', 'White','Black', 'Pink']
del lst[3] # lst = ['Green', 'White','Black']
print(lst)
```